# Embedding a Manifest File in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#

My understanding is that you can right click the project and choose *New Item* and then *Application Manifest File* to embed the manifest file in the application.

I've done this but when I go to the project properties and look at the *Application Tab*, I can see the manifest is greyed out.  This is the case whether the manifest file I've just created is in the project or not - it's always greyed out.

Although being greyed out it does say *Embed manifest with default settings*.  This says to me one of two things - 1) it is greyed out because there is not a manifest in the debug folder with the dll so you have to rely on an embedded one or 2) the one I have just created is not embedded in the project.

If it is 1), and an embedded one is being used then where is it.  Other than the one I've just created, I cannot find any more!!

I've tried restarting Visual Studio, rebuilding etc.  I've searched the internet and the consensus is that what I've done should work.

The other possibility which has just occurred is that manifest files do not work with dll plugins :-0

Comment: Having a manifest in a DLL is quite unusual, although not entirely invalid.  The vast majority of valid manifest entries only work when they go in the EXE project.  Whatever it is you want to accomplish, never keep it a secret, probably shouldn't be done the way you think it should.

Comment: @HansPassant, It's quite simple really.  I'm writing an add-on for keepass which is a DLL.  I want to store a couple of settings in the registry however I cannot write to the registry as I get an UnauthorisedAccessException so I was thinking of running with elevated permissions as set in a manifest file.  It doesn't seem however possible to achieve this!!

Comment: No.  Write to a key in HKCU instead of HKLM.

Comment: Tried this RegistryKey RK1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree); but for some reason I still get an UnauthorisedAccessException.

Answer (score 1):

> The other possibility which has just occurred is that manifest files do not work with dll plugins :-0

That's correct. Manifests are for executables only for Visual Studio. If you really need to embed a manifest in a DLL, say for registration-free COM activation, you will need to resort to using `mt.exe` via the command line and embedding it your DLL yourself, or invoking `csc.exe` and compiling your application by command line.