# How to get assembly version with revision and build from powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

In my program (.net5+) I can get the version **with revision and build** with:

```
private string GetVersion() => typeof(Shell).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

In AssemblyInfo.cs I have the lines

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.44.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.44.*")]
```

(with non deterministic property set in the project)

`GetVersion()` give then something like 2.44.2342.3435

When I ask from powershell with

```
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($file).FileVersion
```

where `$file` is the path to myprogram.exe, I get

> 2.44.0.0

(ie., it works, but I need revision and build numbers) and with

```
[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($file).Version.ToString()
```

I get

> "Could not load file or assembly 'myprogram.exe' or one
> of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

(the file exists, so it's about the manifest). But my project file was properly configured:

[image: manifest]

So, how do I get the result of `GetVersion()` from powershell ?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but the file version of a DLL is not the same as an assembly version. An assembly is usually a DLL but not always. A DLL can be an assembly or it can be an unmanaged library (aka a "dynamic linked library"... the original meaning. You might be asking for the wrong attribute/property...

Comment: @Kit yes you're right, I updated the OP to make the distinction; but in the end, what I need is the assembly version with revions and build; the FileVersion point was that it works.

Comment: Is `myprogram.exe` an (executable) assembly or is it an executable (non-assembly)? It appears to be the latter. That's what `was expected to contain an assembly manifest` typically means.

Comment: All assemblies have a manifest. If one isn't found, it's not an assembly, so calls to get assembly attributes are going to fail (your last attempt), but succeed on file attributes (your first attempt). I suspect I may be right, and the lack of specificity on revision/build is going to give you the `0.0`. I may need to make this an answer :)

Comment: @Kit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/al-exe-assembly-linker

Comment: @Kit also, dll don't have manifests, only exe eventually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633132/embedding-a-manifest-file-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Er, OK. But something along the way does *not* have a manifest. I suggest using dotPeek or something to find out which. What is the value of `$file` that breaks your call?

Comment: @Kit $file is the path to the binary, and it is correct. (updated OP)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this Powershell script the other day, it works with .Net Core projects to increment the Revision number on each build (via a PreBuild or PostBuild event):

```
# Load the assembly containing the Version class 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Version 

# Set the path to the csproj file and load its content 
$projectFilePath = "relative/OSNeutral/path/to/your/project.csproj" 
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $projectFilePath)
 
# Get the current version number 
$currentVersion = [System.Version]($xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version) 

# Increment the Revision number by 1 
$newVersion = New-Object System.Version($currentVersion.Major, $currentVersion.Minor, $currentVersion.Build, $currentVersion.Revision + 1) 

# Update the version number in the csproj file 
$xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version = $newVersion.ToString() 

# Save the updated csproj file 
$xml.Save($projectFilePath)
```

My project files look like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <Version>1.0.1.87</Version>

      <AssemblyVersion>1.0.1.87</AssemblyVersion>   <-- you can have this and edit the above script to work with AssemblyVersion
```

Comment: That's a good alternative, but I'm using the automatic revision and build.

Comment: Very helpful! If anyone else runs into an error related to System.Version not taking 5 arguments, enclose the segment dealing with the revision version increment in parentheses as such:  ```$newVersion = New-Object System.Version($currentVersion.Major, $currentVersion.Minor, $currentVersion.Build, ($currentVersion.Revision + 1)) ```. Also, if you get an error about not being able to import System.Version, drop that line entirely. You may not need to import it, as was my case.